# String arrays methods and if statement

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, if-statement

here, it gives b's element as null rather than storing array a's value. Basically, I can't go inside the if statement

```
public class Dil {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "is2 sentence4 This1 a3";
        String a[]=s.split(" ");
        String b[]=new String[a.length];
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        for(int i=1;i<a.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<a.length-1;j++){
                if(a[j].charAt(a[j].length()-1)==i){
                    b[i-1]=a[j];
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
    }
}
```

Comment: You're comparing an int with a char. I dont think thats what u wanted to achive

Answer (score 1):

You have two unrelated problems.

> *here, it gives b's element as null rather than storing array a's value*.

That's because your instantiating a new and empty array, only providing to it the size of array `a` (not the values!), with:

```java
String b[] = new String[a.length];
```

If you want to copy an array, better do:

```java
String[] a = new String[] {/*..your array..*/};
String[] b = new String[a.length];
System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, a.length);
```

or

```java
String[] b = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
```

---

> *Basically, I can't go inside the if statement*

Variable of type `char`, indeed can store a number, as under the hood, chars are represented as ASCII codes.

Therefore, your:

```
(a[j].charAt(a[j].length()-1)==i)
```

would only evaluate to `true`, when `i` will be equal to [ASCII code](https://www.asciitable.com/) of the char in question; however, characters represented with [0; 31] codes, are *non-printable* ones, which, most likely, will not be include in your strings and hence - your `if`'s condition will not evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I think thats more like what u wanted:

```
public class Dil {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "is2 sentence4 This1 a3";
        String a[]=s.split(" ");
        String b[]=new String[a.length];
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        for(int i=1;i<a.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<a.length-1;j++){
                if(a[j].charAt(a[j].length()-1)==((char)(i + '0'))){
                    b[i-1]=a[j];
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
    }
}
```

But that just works if `0<=i<=9`